# Ifinite/lazy Scrolling in PHP using Ajax shows this Access to XMLHttpRequest at

Tags: php, ajax, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to implement Infinite scrolling on my website where I'm loading users' data.
and for that purpose I'm using this Ajax script

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 var limit = 10;
 var start = 0;
 var action = 'inactive';
 function load_country_data(limit, start)
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"pagination.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{limit:limit, start:start},
   cache:false,
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#load_data').append(data);
    if(data == '')
    {
     $('#load_data_message').html("<button type='button' class='btn btn-info'>No Data Found</button>");
     action = 'active';
    }
    else
    {
     $('#load_data_message').html("<button type='button' class='btn btn-info'>Loading data</button>");
     action = "inactive";
    }
   }
  });
 }

 if(action == 'inactive')
 {
  action = 'active';
  load_country_data(limit, start);
 }
 $(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $("#load_data").height() && action == 'inactive')
  {
   action = 'active';
   start = start + limit;
   setTimeout(function(){
    load_country_data(limit, start);
   }, 1000);
  }
 });

});
```

So now when i run that page it shows this error in console log

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com/pagination.php' from origin 'http://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

But this thing work in Postman perfectly and gives me output.
Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to why it would work in Postman in the first place, but this is a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors) issue, specifically [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin).

It also looks like you're trying to access your `pagination.php` script over SSL when the page running the JS code you've included is not loaded using `SSL`, which I believe is a CORS violation apart from the one cited in the error you're receiving.

Comment: Then how to load JS using SSL? Can you please guide me?